# Python multiple clickable Notifications on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, notifications, libraries

I'm working on a script which goes through a list of links and looks if there is a product matching the users preferences. If there is a product matching the preference, then it should send out a Windows notification and a click on said notification should redirect the user to the web site.

Unfortunately it's not possible to create multiple Win10toast notifications without stopping the script until the time of the notification is expired and plyer has no function with a click event.

Here is an example with plyer:

```
from plyer import notification

notification.notify(
    title = "Sample Notification",
    message = "This is a sample notification",
    timeout = 30
)

notification.notify(
    title = "Sample Notification",
    message = "This is a sample notification",
    timeout = 30
)

#Works as intended -> It creates two notifications right after another without waiting for the other one to disappear
#Unfortunately nothing happens when I click the notification!
```

Here is the code from win10toast

```
from wintoast import ToastNotifier
import webbrowser
link = "https://www.google.com"

toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Sample Notification", "This is a sample notification" , threaded=True, duration=50, callback_on_click=lambda:  myFunction(link))
toaster.show_toast("Sample Notification2", "This is a sample notification" , threaded=True, duration=50, callback_on_click=lambda:  myFunction(link))
# Waits 50 seconds before the second notification is being shown


def myFunction(produktLink):
    webbrowser.open(produktLink, new=2)
```

Is there any library or another way to achive that?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need them to show at the same time? If not, I would just create a queue, and put the notifications there, and use another process to poll the queue and show the notifications.

Comment: Yeah there is: I'm planning to show the user the notification for around an hour and stopping the script for that time would be unreasonable.

Comment: One quick'n'dirty fix would be to collect during the hour when notification #1 is shown all the links you want to show, and for the duration of next hour, show in notification #2 the collection of links, be it 1 or 20. If the notifications need to be real time (1h delay is unacceptable), you could use separate Gmail account for sending emails programmatically. If I remember correctly, Gmail offers around 1000 free emails per day.